# How to not open all dropdowns at once?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I know the title seems very basic and easy but pls help me, so basically when i try to open one menu, it opens all menus

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
  function handleClick() {
    setActive(!active);
  }

  const text = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Hello",
      subText: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Sub Hello"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Bye",
      subText: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Sub Bye"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", padding: 4 }}>
      {text?.map(({ name, id, subText }) => (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <ul style={{ width: 100 }}>
            <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handleClick}>
              {name}
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            {active &&
              subText?.map(({ name, id }) => (
                <ul key={id}>
                  <li>{name}</li>
                </ul>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the live code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-moser-dh4mit?file=/src/App.js:0-1051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the parent menu id for checking which submenu should be opened would help.
Attaching the changed code below.
Just passed id and hold it in the state when clicked. otherwise the state would be undefined.

```
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(undefined);
  function handleClick(id) {
    setActive(id === active ? undefined :id);
  }

  const text = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Hello",
      subText: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Sub Hello"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Bye",
      subText: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Sub Bye"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", padding: 4 }}>
      {text?.map(({ name, id, subText }) => (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <ul style={{ width: 100 }}>
            <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>
              {name}
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            {active === id &&
              subText?.map(({ name, id }) => (
                <ul key={id}>
                  <li>{name}</li>
                </ul>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: if the anwer helped you, could you please accept it and increase the useful?

Comment: i did, sadly i cant upvote as im not yet 15 reputation points yet

Comment: ok. no issues. ;)